# Enable Cesium's requestRenderMode via OLCesium

Tags: openlayers, cesiumjs

I have a map I am displaying in 2D/3D modes using [Ol-Cesium](https://github.com/openlayers/ol-cesium) 2.9 and Cesium 1.70.

Whereas the map works fine, I am now trying to enable [Cesium's Request Render Mode](https://cesium.com/blog/2018/01/24/cesium-scene-rendering-performance/):

```
// Create the 3D map passing the previously created ol.Map
var map3d = new olcs.OLCesium({map: olMap});

// Trying to enable Cesium's requestRenderMode - This does nothing; the map still renders continuously
var scene = map3d.getCesiumScene();
scene.requestRenderMode = true;
scene.maximumRenderTimeChange = Infinity;
```

However, it's not making any difference in CPU usage, either Firefox or Chrome.

Any advice? Or may this be a limitation in Ol-Cesium?

Comment: In cesium.js you can see the fps by the command: viewer.scene.debugShowFramesPerSecond. You need to see that when requestRenderMode is enabled, there are no frames... Can you add this commad to OI Cesium and tell us what do you see? Also i recommend to you to ask cesium questions in cesium forum, there cesium developers will try to help